# Is Microsoft StreamInsight Ready for Primetime?

Tags: c#, events, real-time, streaminsight

I am wondering if Microsoft StreamInsight is ready for production code?  It seems like a great way to handle real-time event processing.  But I'm just concerned that it is a half-baked solution and not ready for a production environment with thousands of transactions and users actually beating it up.

If you have any experiences you can share then that would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use it but the showstopper for me was that the events could not contain nested structures, nor could they be larger than some fixed size (16k, maybe). If not for those restrictions, it did look pretty solid, though.

Comment: philip: Events are objects. The objects cannot contain other objects.

Comment: The limit is 16k, including whatever overhead the event came with.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb is: If it is from Microsoft and within 12 months of it's first release then it's not production ready.

First run products from MS have a high probability of being killed within the first year of release.  Especially those released with little fanfare.

Also, they tend to leave a lot of needed functionality out in the first release that you usually don't know you need until you've invested a lot of time in it.  Some companies call this "client driven" development; I call it "didn't bother using it ourselves first" development

If, however, you see a service pack or a rev 2 around the 12 month mark then the probability of it staying around for awhile goes up significantly.

Comment: You have put it nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Chris,
We will be very interested to know the scenarios you plan to deploy StreamInsight and to hear your concerns and questions through our forum. I have provided a link to the forum for your convenience.

Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/streaminsight

Thank you for your interest in Microsoft StreamInsight.

Ram Krishnan
(for) Microsoft StreamInsight

Comment: real-time data will be processed from an oil well drilling system